# Python OpenCV- Problems reading files on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I need to read a folder with a lot of .bmp files, and put all of the images on a lits of images. I do not know how to handle the adress. I was doing some thing like this:

```
adress = "c:/Users/My Name/Desktop/assignment/*.bmp"

imageArray = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(adress)]

numImg = len(imageArray)
```

Inside the assignment folder, there is the Images folder with all the images I need. How to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

#### Change working directory first:

If you change to the directory of interest first, it may be easier.

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/mydir")

image_type = "*.bmp"

imageArray = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(image_type)]

numImg = len(imageArray)
```

This [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python) has some nice info about reading files in directories